# Gridview displaying XML (can't figure out the path for the datafields)

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have the following code on a webform (not exact but it shows what I'm working with, I will have more datafield sections but just wanted to show):

The XML below has been simplified because it includes 4 "days" of data... I can't figure out what to put into the datafields, I have tried a few things including (to get for example, "period" and "precipitation"):

<asp:BoundField DataField="/forecasts/daily/automated/period" HeaderText="Period" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="/forecasts/daily/automated/precipitation/textSummary" HeaderText="Precip" ItemStyle-Width="150" /

Tried with and without "/" etc. but can't figure it out when it's nested like this... any ideas?

````
    RowStyle-BackColor="#A1DCF2" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="White" AlternatingRowStyle-ForeColor="#000"
    runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="" HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>```


the .cs:

        private void BindGrid()
        {
            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/AlpineFX.xml"));
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }

And now the XML I am trying to get data from:

```<?xml version="1.0"?>
<siteData xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <license>Provided by RWDI - Consulting Engineers and Scientists © 2020</license>
    <location lat="50.12" lon="-122.95" timezone="Canada/Pacific" offset="-7">Whistler Blackcomb</location>
    <dateTime name="xmlCreation" zone="UTC" utcOffset="0">
        <year>2021</year>
        <month name="January">1</month>
        <day name="Saturday">23</day>
        <hour>14</hour>
        <minute>0</minute>
        <date>2021-01-23T14:00:00Z</date>
        <textSummary>Saturday January 23, 2021 at 2:00 PM UTC</textSummary>
    </dateTime>
    <dateTime name="nextXmlCreation" zone="UTC" utcOffset="0">
        <year>2021</year>
        <month name="January">1</month>
        <day name="Saturday">23</day>
        <hour>23</hour>
        <minute>0</minute>
        <date>2021-01-23T23:00:00Z</date>
        <textSummary>Next update by Saturday January 23, 2021 at 11:00 PM UTC</textSummary>
    </dateTime>
    <forecasts>
        <daily>
            <automated>
                <forecast>
                    <period>Today</period>
                    <textSummary>A mix of sun and cloud.</textSummary>
                    <warnings />
                    <iconCode format="gif">02</iconCode>
                    <temperatures>
                        <textSummary />
                        <surfaceTemperature units="C" unitType="metric" class="high">-3</surfaceTemperature>
                        <dewPointTemperature units="C" unitType="metric" class="high">-7</dewPointTemperature>
                        <windChill units="C" unitType="metric" class="high">-3</windChill>
                    </temperatures>
                    <precipitation>
                        <textSummary>Precipitation: Nil.</textSummary>
                    </precipitation>
                    <surfaceWind>
                        <speed units="km/h" unitType="metric">5</speed>
                        <gust units="km/h" unitType="metric">20</gust>
                        <direction>SW</direction>
                        <bearing units="degrees">218</bearing>
                    </surfaceWind>
                    <freezingLevel>
                        <textSummary>Freezing level: 1000 metres.</textSummary>
                        <height class="max" units="m" unitType="metric">1000</height>
                    </freezingLevel>
                    <relativeHumidity>
                        <rh units="%" class="min">68</rh>
                        <rh units="%" class="max">99</rh>
                    </relativeHumidity>
                    <pressure>
                        <surfacePressure units="mBar" class="min">855</surfacePressure>
                        <surfacePressure units="mBar" class="max">860</surfacePressure>
                    </pressure>
                    <solarRadiation>
                        <solarRad units="W/m^2" class="max">365</solarRad>
                    </solarRadiation>
                    <sun>
                        <sunrise>2021-01-24T07:56:17-08:00</sunrise>
                        <sunset>2021-01-24T16:51:22-08:00</sunset>
                        <sunshineHours>8</sunshineHours>
                    </sun>
                    <alpine>
                        <temperatures height="1800" description="alpine" height_units="m">
                            <textSummary>Alpine temperature: High -3 °C.</textSummary>
                            <temperature units="C" unitType="metric" class="high">-3</temperature>
                        </temperatures>
                        <temperatures height="2200" description="ridge" height_units="m">
                            <textSummary />
                            <temperature units="C" unitType="metric" class="high">-4</temperature>
                        </temperatures>
                        <winds height="2200" description="ridge" height_units="m">
                            <textSummary>Ridge wind southwest: 15 km/h.</textSummary>
                            <speed units="km/h" unitType="metric">15</speed>
                            <direction>SW</direction>
                            <bearing units="degrees">244</bearing>
                        </winds>
                        <winds height="1800" description="alpine" height_units="m">
                            <textSummary />
                            <speed units="km/h" unitType="metric">15</speed>
                            <direction>SW</direction>
                            <bearing units="degrees">244</bearing>
                        </winds>
                    </alpine>
                </forecast>
</automated>
</daily>

</forecasts>
</siteData>
````

Comment: Well, I'm no ASP guy, but in XPath you would write `siteData/forecasts/daily/automated/forecast/period` instead of `/forecasts/daily/automated/period` and `/forecasts/daily/automated/precipitation/textSummary` would become `siteData/forecasts/daily/automated/forecast/precipitation/textSummary`. Seems you only missed some path parts.

Comment: interesting you say that, I did try with siteData preceeding forecasts but it did not work either... came up with an error

Comment: Hmm ok, seems you are then already inside the root node, have you tried to add `...automated/forecast/...`?  Because you're also missing the `/forecast/` element.

Comment: I get the following error: "A field or property with the name 'siteData/forecasts/automated/forecast/period' was not found on the selected data source"... have tried multiple versions of the nesting like the above but no luck and the same error, can't find the field or property =(

Comment: If you really wrote `siteData/forecasts/automated/forecast/period` you're now missing the `daily` element. Make sure that the element structure in your tree exactly match your path. `siteData/forecasts/daily/automated/forecast/period`

Comment: sorry, bad paraphrasing... had already tried with daily included, with and without siteData, with and without forecasts etc. and same error each time

Comment: Well, last chance for me to help you, short google search came up with [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/2132253.aspx?Write+and+Read+xml+and+bind+in+nested+gridview). Good Luck!